# Java incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public int[] Test(int[] x, int target) {
        target = 100;
        int i;
        int j;
        int sum;
        for (i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j > 3; j++) {
            sum = x[i] + x[j];
                if (sum == target) {
                    return x[i];
                    return x[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a code to return 2 elements (from an array) which give me the target integer 100 when summed.
I keep getting the following 2 errors:

```
incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[] 
                    return x[i];                         
incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[] 
                    return x[j];
```

Comment: @David if the goal is to return two items, it isn't

Comment: No, it is actually trying to return twice from the same method. I suppose you want to return a two-element array with the values of `x[i]` and `x[j]`? You have to create said array, fill it, and return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return new int[]{x[i], x[j]};
```

You want to return an array `int[]`, not a single `int` value.

```
return x[i];
return x[j];
```

doesn't make any sense because a `return` statement immediately interrupts the flow (returns control to the invoker) making the following statements unreachable.

You are also missing a return statement at the end. When `target` hasn't been met, you still have to return something from the method.

It could be an empty array:

```
return new int[0];
```

However, usually, we throw an exception saying the given arguments didn't make the method work:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("The target wasn't met for the given input.");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return x[i];
return x[j];
```

A method can only return one value.
turn the above in this:

```
int[] tmp = new int[2];
tmp[0] = x[i];
tmp[1] = x[j];
return tmp;
```